# How to Erase stroke on canvas in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, erase

I want to Erase the InkStroke on canvas using C# Point-By-Point, How to solve it?

So far, I just found that InkManipulationMode.erasing mode is used to erase the inkStroke, but the problem is it will erase the whole inkStroke. And what I want is erasing point-by-point.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? what are you facing problem ? Check this sample app : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-simplified-ink-sample-11614bbf

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the way getting the points on both DrawingStroke and ErasingStroke, then deleting the intersection, and using CreateStroke API to create two new strokes. But the new strokes is unsmooth and the preformance is poor. Any good ideas?